# Should a phrase be repeated in one sentence for clarity?

Tags: editing

In my dissertation, we analyze three types of data: (1) high contrast, (2) low contrast, and (3) zero contrast. Would it be grammatically correct to say "high, low, and zero contrast" or does "contrast" need to be repated 3 times?

If I write "zero and high contrast," is it obvious that "zero" is a "contrast?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be clear to your expert audience from the topic of your paper that *zero* in the phrase *zero and high contrast* must mean *zero contrast*, but if you want to absolutely sure, you might want to use all three full terms at least a few times in a prominent place like the abstract and introduction. Once you have thus made it clear that you are writing about three kinds of contrast, there will be no doubt for your readers that *high, low, and zero contrast* mean *high contrast, low contrast, and zero contrast*.